# Project server 2013 database locked

Tags: 2013, content-database, project-server

Today we noticed that our Project server 2013 database is locked somehow.
Weird thing is, when we check whether from CA that site SC or via SharePoint shell, we get answer that site collection is not locked, not in single user mode, etc. It shows it is ok, but when we want to create new Project site, we get simple error message

> GeneralDalDatabaseIsReadOnly

We searched for a while but found no appropriate solution for this. Also what might be useful information is that jobs connected to Project server, scheduled for nightly run are in running mode for a few days already, with no change of status or event.

We recycled app pool of WA in which Project server site collection is.
Also we tried stopping windows services tied with Project server and re run them again, but again same message.

Any suggestion or what might help or what might be problem could be very useful to us.

EDIT:
Forgot to write, on dashboard after anything is tried yellow ribbon with a warning is displayed.

> This site is read-only at the moment.

Comment: Have you checked the related Content DB is not locked or offline in the CA > Content DB?

Comment: Yes. It says it is unlocked. Users still can edit everything! funny thing. What doesn't work is creating new projects. We also noticed that jobs from few days ago are still in run, but they cannot be stopped, restarted, etc. Whatever we try they keep showing as running. We thought of IIS reset, but we can try that only tonight.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.
We have 2 SQL servers in ShP farm, working in Always On availability group.
While we were configuring and starting Project server 2013 on production servers one SQL instance was primary, what happened here was that somehow Project jobs still kept looking on that instance, even tough primary sql changed in mean time.
After switch happened that active instance, now became secondary and read only, while previous secondary (read only) became primary instance.

So we are now checking where we have to clear cache and to check for jobs to run smoothly, cause we don't want to keep only one instance as primary.